# resource file not regenerating when rebuilding (hello world tutorial)

Tags: monodevelop, xamarin.android

I downloaded monodriod yesterday and was following the hello world tutorial, and came across a problem in monodevelop with resources i couldnt figure out.

When i changed the names of the two string resources in String.xml, the partial String class in Resource.designer.cs wouldnt update when i rebuild the solution. I tried building cleaning restarting the solution, but nothing worked. I then tried removing the partial String class hoping that might force itself to regenerate, but no luck that just brought a compile error.

```
\HelloM4A\HelloM4A\Resources\layout\main.axml(0,0): Error: No resource found that matches   
the given name (at 'text' with value '@string/hello'). (HelloM4A)
```

can anybody give me a pointer to what i have been doing wrong.

thanks

tut:
http://docs.xamarin.com/android/getting_started/hello_world

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you have not updated `main.axml` to use the new string name:

Use: `@string/<SOME_NEW_NAME_HERE>`

Main.axml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout ... >
    <Button ...
            android:text="@string/<SOME_NEW_NAME_HERE>" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Strings.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    ...
    <string name="<SOME_NEW_NAME_HERE>">Hello Mono for Android</string>
</resources>
```